# Mysterious hang/freeze randomly for FSFindFolder on Mac OS

Tags: macos, cocoa

**Background:**

1. We released a framework on Mac OS, build on mac10.8, xcode4.3/4.5, target platform mac10.6 and later.
2. The cocoa applications integrated with this framework, hang/freezing randomly.
3. We cannot reproduce it with all real applications, so we write a test application to verify the framework
4. All real cocoa applications integrated the framework in non-main thread.
5. With test application, we cannot reproduce it by integration it in main thread
6. With test application, we can reproduce it by integration it in a new created thread, but sometimes randomly
7. Finally, we located the suspected code below, comments out these code, no hang/freeze/beach ball:

   ```
   FSRef folderFSRef;
   if ( FSFindFolder(kUserDomain, kApplicationSupportFolderType, kCreateFolder, &folderFSRef) != noErr )
   {
       return false;
   }
   ```
8. If we take in above code, we have hang here.
9. But if we sleep 10 seconds before these code, then no hang here.
10. the hang happened after these codes, that means hang happened on other place, but decided by these code
11. Here are the call stack when hang/freezing, simple test application, so simple callstack;

    > ```
    >    Sampling process 13312 for 3 seconds with 1 millisecond of run time between samples<br/>
    >    Sampling completed, processing symbols...<br/>
    >    Analysis of sampling fooPIPTestApplication (pid 13312) every 1 millisecond<br/>
    >    Process:         fooPIPTestApplication [13312]<br/>
    >    Path:            /Users/triger/p4/foopip/main/public/test/macosx/debug/fooPIPTestApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/fooPIPTestApplication<br/>
    >    Load Address:    0x100000000<br/>
    >    Identifier:      com.foo.SimpleTestApplication<br/>
    >    Version:         ??? (1.0)<br/>
    >    Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)<br/>
    >    Parent Process:  debugserver [13310]<br/>
    >    <br/>
    >    Date/Time:       2013-12-13 19:21:08.875 +0800<br/>
    >    OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.3 (12D78)<br/>
    >    Report Version:  7<br/>
    >    <br/>
    >    Call graph:<br/>
    >        2730 Thread_289593   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)<br/>
    >        + 2730 start  (in fooPIPTestApplication) + 52  [0x100001714]<br/>
    >        +   2730 main  (in fooPIPTestApplication) + 398  [0x10000b49e]  main.m:121<br/>
    >        +     2730 NSApplicationMain  (in AppKit) + 869  [0x7fff937c5c06]<br/>
    >        +       2730 -[NSApplication run]  (in AppKit) + 517  [0x7fff938211d3]<br/>
    >        +         2730 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]  (in AppKit) + 128  [0x7fff93829e22]<br/>
    >        +           2730 _DPSNextEvent  (in AppKit) + 685  [0x7fff9382a563]<br/>
    >        +             2730 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode  (in HIToolbox) + 62  [0x7fff943fcae3]<br/>
    >        +               2730 ReceiveNextEventCommon  (in HIToolbox) + 356  [0x7fff943fcc52]<br/>
    >        +                 2730 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode  (in HIToolbox) + 209  [0x7fff943fceb4]<br/>
    >        +                   2730 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 290  [0x7fff8f9100e2]<br/>
    >        +                     2730 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 1078  [0x7fff8f910916]<br/>
    >        +                       2730 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort  (in CoreFoundation) + 195  [0x7fff8f90b233]<br/>
    >        +                         2730 mach_msg  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 70  [0x7fff8fb65c42]<br/>
    >        +                           2730 mach_msg_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8fb66686]<br/>
    >        2730 Thread_289616   DispatchQueue_2: com.apple.libdispatch-manager  (serial)<br/>
    >          2730 _dispatch_mgr_thread  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 54  [0x7fff97b839ee]<br/>
    >            2730 _dispatch_mgr_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 883  [0x7fff97b83dea]<br/>
    >              2730 kevent  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8fb68d16]<br/>
    >    <br/>
    >    Total number in stack (recursive counted multiple, when >=5):<br/>
    >    <br/>
    >    Sort by top of stack, same collapsed (when >= 5):<br/>
    >            kevent  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        2730<br/>
    >            mach_msg_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        2730<br/>
    >    <br/>
    >    Binary Images:<br/>
    >    <br/>
    > ```
12. I know "FSFindFolder" is deprecated on 10.8, but I don't think that means it has bug on 10.8

**Questions:**
1. Is this a bug with FSFindFolder? But seems no one reported it.
2. Seems above code messed up something, then somebody comes across it later, then hang.
3. Any ideas?

Comment: Your app isn't frozen in that stack trace, and certainly not in `FSFindFolder`. Note that `FSFindFolder` isn't present in the stack trace. Your app, as of that sample, was simply idling. If your app is hanging, you need to sample it during the hang.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But there is a spinning beach ball, and I cannot click down menu bar.So, I say it's hung. Then, I suppose this FSFindFolder messed up something, then hang, then I sampled it.

Comment: OK, so it did hang at some point. You need to sample it *then*, *while* it is hung, and have *that* sample in your question. The sample you have now just shows the application idling normally.

Comment: The backtrace is the final sample, no change any more. Before this(just after launching the app), there are some additional thread stack, like:   1403 Thread_833335
    + 1403 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff9a6711d1]
    +   1403 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 412  [0x7fff9a686d13]
    +     1403 _pthread_workq_return  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 25  [0x7fff9a686f4c]
    +       1403 __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8fb686d6], but later, all these kinds of start_wqthread disappeared in backtrace. What can complete these start_wqthread?

Comment: Those look like worker threads. They're just sitting around waiting for something to do; there is nothing to complete. Besides which, even if a worker thread were hung, that wouldn't necessarily hang the main thread—and if it did, you'd see evidence of whatever the main thread was waiting for in the main thread's part of the sample.

Comment: We do nothing in main thread, actually only a menus bar with some menu items, we have commented out all IBAction methods. As you see the backtrace for main thread, only system call like "NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode". I was suspecting thread-safe issue against main thread when we do something in secondary thread. Seems UI in secondary thread has problems, but no one mentioned the thread-safe issue with non-UI functions. Weird!

Comment: In fact, the framework has code for UI, like popping up a modal dialog. But for the current test scenario, the UI code are not touched.

Comment: Apple's “Thread-Safety Summary” outlines in broad terms what's safe and what's unsafe to use from secondary threads. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html If you mean to suggest that `FSFindFolder` is not thread-safe, that's not true unless you're targeting Mac OS X before 10.3. (See Folders.h.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bug for FSFindFolder.

I also opened a bug on https://bugreport.apple.com with bug# 15664470. So far, no response.  :(
It's about MT-safe, I think. Although, document says MT-safe from 10.3.

I have written a simpler demo application to verify this issue.
Only calling FSFindFolder on the secondary thread, and nothing in main thread, then the application will hang.
If move it to main thread, no problem.
If replace it with NSFileManager's URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:, no problem.
Same result on Mac10.8 and Mac10.6, so nothing to do with deprecated.